# Sharing a variable between controllers through a service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

[Here is my plunker:](http://plnkr.co/edit/Vluyqawj05GoZWmsbTCQ)

From what I understand, since the Service Variable being shared is an object, the object that gets loaded to the service by controller 1 should be plainly seen by controller2 without the need for $watches or listeners or anything.  Am I wrong?  How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have fixed your plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/JNBmsjzdj6SHOSK4kPNh.

Your service has an object which you put into a model on your $scope ($scope.item). So far so good. However, you then update your service object with a new object reference ($scope.thisObject) so that $scope.item and myService.myObject are now referencing to completely different objects.

You should only update object properties. See the plunk for details.

So instead of writing:

```
app.factory('myService',function(){
  var service = {
      myObject:{},
      changeProperty: function(newProperty){
        this.myObject = newProperty;
      }
  };
  return service;
});
```

You should use:

```
app.factory('myService',function(){
  var service = {
      myObject:{},
      changeProperty: function(newProperty){
        this.myObject.text = newProperty.text;
      }
  };
  return service;
});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Gah!  I feel so silly.  I remember this now from [the Best Practices Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY) done a while back.  He spent a while covering this exact bug, now that I think of it.  His final words on the subject were "If it doesn't have a period, you are doing it wrong"